# How to put dynamic search box on a table with Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I have a table and I want to put a search box on top of the table which dynamically search in table data and filter it for enabling user to find table for easier.

my table code is:

```
<mat-card class="fields-list" *ngIf="tableShown">
      <mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-actions align="end">
          <button type="button" class="topia-btn topia-primary-btn action-buttons" (click)="addClicked()">
            Add New Office
          </button>
        </mat-card-actions>
        <mat-table #table [dataSource]="officePinList">
          <ng-container cdkColumnDef="label">
            <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef fxFlex="20%">Label</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let officePin" fxFlex="20%">{{officePin.label}}</mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container cdkColumnDef="postalAddress">
            <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef fxFlex="55%">Postal Adress</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let officePin" fxFlex="55%">{{officePin.postalAddress}}</mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container cdkColumnDef="trash-icon">
            <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef fxFlex="15%"></mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let officePin" fxFlex="15%">
              <mat-icon (click)="deleteGroupOffices(officePin.id)" mat-list-icon matTooltip="Delete" class="icon">
                delete_forever
              </mat-icon>
              <mat-icon (click)="editField(officePin.id)" mat-list-icon matTooltip="Edit" class="icon">edit</mat-icon>
            </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <mat-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
          <mat-row class="table-row" *cdkRowDef="let officePin; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>

        </mat-table>
```

My table data source is *officePinList*

How can I filter table data with dynamic search box for the table exactly like this:
https://ciphertrick.com/demo/angularajaxsearch/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add an input search box:

### Html

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
</mat-form-field>
```

And afterwards you need to add method that actually adds filter to your source:

### Ts

```
applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
  this.officePinList.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: ts part is having error. TS2322. type string cannot be assignable to ....

Comment: What type is your **officePinList** source? Is it **MatTableDataSource**?

Comment: officePinList: OfficePin[];   it is a list containing models called OfficePin

Comment: try to change it to type `officePinList = new MatTableDataSource(data)` where data is array of type OfficePin[]

Comment: when I change filtervalue string to officePin then trim is giving error as property trim does not exist on type OfficePin ts2339

Comment: your **dataSource** should be of type **MatTableDataSource** to support filtering out of the box

Comment: applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.tableDataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }-- trim still not found undefined

Comment: Have you added html part? Because it shouldn't be undefined if you bound it like `(keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)"`

Comment: No problem, I'm glad that it helped!